# Status line in Eclipse Scout

Tags: statusbar, eclipse-scout

I would like to have status line in Eclipse scout application, that is always visible.

For example :

[image]

How to get to this line ?

In RAP this line is not visible. Is possible to get it in RAP ? Or is there another general solution ?

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only status bar managed by Scout is the one that you can find on tables (and Table Field). See this Forum entry: [Table status bar](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/367326/).

Depending on the renderer you use, the platform might also provide one:

- SWT: You have the Eclipse RCP Workbench and you get all the features.
- Swing: I think we instantiate a `JDesktop` and with the default Look And Feel you see a status bar (like in your screenshot)
- RAP: I think there is no status bar in this case.

I you need one for RAP; you need to do a custom implementation.

Comment: aha, ok thanks. Is there a way to add label on Desktop and not to forms ?